# Fundamental solution of Laplacian in 2d doesn't agree with 3d version physically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, greens-function, fundamental-solution

The fundamental solution of the Laplacian, with $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, is

$$
\Phi(x, y) = -\frac{1}{4\pi|x - y|}
$$
So, say, the further away $x$ is from some point source $y$ the lesser the magnitude of the 'effect' of $\Phi$. And as they become very far apart $\Phi \to 0$.

However for the fundamental solution of the Laplacian, with $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, is

$$
\Phi(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln |x - y|
$$
This seems to be in conflict with the 3d fundamental solution as now the further apart $x$ and $y$ are the greater the magnitude of the effect of $\Phi$.

Am I missing something here? Intuitively it doesn't seem right that the further we are from some source point, the greater the effect we feel?

Comment: I believe that it doesn't seem right intuitively, because you have spent too much of your time in 3D.

Comment: you don't feel $\Phi$ (which is defined up to a constant anyway), only its gradient

Comment: @user8268 Can you elaborate? $\Phi$, and not its gradient, is used in single layer potentials to represent solutions to the Laplace equation?